# how to separate values with spaces in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, spaces

So I have this program that gives the binary values of the ascii values plus 1 of a user input string.

```
text = input()
bitString = ''
for ch in text:
    new = ord(ch) + 1

    decimal = new
    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = decimal // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString

print(bitString)
```

If the user inputs "abcde" the output will be

```
11001101100101110010011000111100010
```

How do I get the binary values to be separated by spaces, where the output would be

```
1100010 1100011 1100100 1100101 1100110
```

?

Comment: okay so I tried that and it doesn't seem to make a difference? I still get the output without the spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very slight change in your code to add space:

```
text = input()
bitString = ''
for ch in text:
    new = ord(ch) + 1

    decimal = new
    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = decimal // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString

    bitString = " " + bitString

print(bitString)
```

Output:

```
1100010 1100011 1100100 1100101 1100110
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input = 'abcde'
bitString = ''
for i in list(input):
    bitString =  bitString + bin(ord(i)+1)[2:] + ' '
print(bitString)
```

I hope you want to get this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
text = input()
bitString = ''
for ch in text:
    new = ord(ch) + 1

    decimal = new
    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = decimal // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString
splitStr = [bitString[i:i+7] for i in range(0, len(bitString), 7)]
print(" ".join(splitStr[::-1]))
```

Result:

```
1100010 1100011 1100100 1100101 1100110
```

> OR

```
text = input()
bitString = ''
for ch in text:
    new = ord(ch) + 1
    decimal = new
    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = decimal // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString
    bitString = " " + bitString

print(" ".join(bitString.split()[::-1]))
```

Result:

```
1100010 1100011 1100100 1100101 1100110
```

Comment: @zeurosis Try the above solution

Comment: what is the significance of 7?

Comment: Splitting string into parts of len(7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
revBitString = bitString[::-1]
print(' '.join([revBitString[i:i+7][::-1] for i in range(0,len(revBitString),7)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using space at the end like this

```
    remainder = decimal % 2
    decimal = decimal // 2
    bitString = str(remainder) + bitString + " "
```

This should solve

Comment: I tried that and still got the output without the spaces... not sure why it's not working